# How to check how long is used to download a file from a linux server by using curl command?

Tags: centos, networking, curl, time

I am testing the latency between 2 linux servers. A linux server is server and B linux server is client. I can download the file successfully by using `curl` command. But the time is too quick could be around 300-500ms.

When I tried to use `curl` by following command I can't see time spent with downloading the file. Like to know how could I see the time spent when I download a small file?

```
curl -0 "http://server IP/filename" --output filename
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2191k  100 2191k    0     0  8278k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 8302k
```

Comment: If you want to test latency between two servers, consider using a tool made for the job such as `iperf`

Comment: time taken to download is more a measure of speed than latency .... consider if the latency were 2 seconds (exaggerated stupid figure I know), and the speed was 8mbit/s ... a 1 megabyte file would take 3 seconds to download ... but you measure the "time spent to download" it would be 1 second, but the the total time taken is 3 seconds ... neither of which are the latency

Answer (score 0):

Curl has a feature where it can print to stdout information about a completed transfer.  It involves the `--write-out` or `-w` option with a corresponding format string (similar to `printf` format strings).

The man page describes quite a few format specifications, including several that describe the elapsed time between the start of a connection and various stages of the session (DNS lookup, TCP connection ready, redirect to a different URL, start of transfer, etc.) and the end of a connection (or "transfer").  However, for your purposes I think you only need two.  Using an example similar to yours:

```
curl -0 --output filename --write-out 'xfer_start=%{time_starttransfer}\nxfer_end=%{time_total}\n' "https://www.google.com/"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15166    0 15166    0     0  64085      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 67404
xfer_start=0.214270
xfer_end=0.236651
```

I have used this feature to create monitoring scripts to test the responsiveness of web servers between the time the URL is sent to when the HTTP response code comes back.  It seems to work pretty well.